# Erro com.google.android.gms no ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: java, android

Meu código esta dando esse erro:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

Porque sera?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'fabiohcnobre'
            keyPassword 'xxxx'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/fabio/AndroidStudioProjects/KEY_STORE/android.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 17
        versionName '1.1.7'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.10'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.6.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'

}
```

Comment: Qual a TargetSDK do seu app?

Comment: Cola o fonte do build.gradle (Module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro informa que há um conflito entre as versões do *google-services plugin* e as api's *com.google.android.gms*.

Você está a usar a versão 9.4.0 das api´s *com.google.firebase* ao mesmo tempo que usa a versão 9.6.1 das *com.google.android.gms*, daí o conflito.

Altere as *com.google.firebase* para a versão 9.6.1

Comment: Ranaral, minha versao do build.grandle esta assim         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'